# How to transform Laptop into Hypervisor bare metal virtual station with passthrough?

Tags: virtualization, bare-metal

I would like to replace my dual boot setup with some hypervisor level 1 system without host OS, one window with complete pass-through so I can play games, and one Linux, instead of installing a virtual machine on a system and virtualize from there...

I would like to boot to something like a Hypervisor with GUI that could let me choose which virtual system to start instead of Linux or windows as host OS.

Tips on where to start or is there any live cd that comes with something like this? tools? tutorials? tried google but too much miss information.

Comment: Suggest you confirm your laptop is ready for virtualization if you have not already done so. See: https://www.technorms.com/8208/check-if-processor-supports-virtualization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing like that I am aware of is called Qubes OS:
https://www.qubes-os.org/

It uses the Xen hypervisor (https://www.xenproject.org/developers/teams/hypervisor.html) to launch different Windows from different guest OSes. You have a main desktop which is used for nothing other than opening windows in the guest OSes. The great part is that you don't have to boot and switch screens. You can see a window from your WindowsOS and a window from your Linux OS on the same desktop. It's amazing.

NOTE: All virtualization causes extra strain on the hardware. There will be performance degradation in any high-end game. Bare-metal install will always give you a better gaming experience.